# Modelling ESR of a parallel plate capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, esr, die

I am trying to model a parallel plate capacitor (on die capacitor generated using metal plates.)

I know the capacitance per unit area, and metal sheet resistance. No knowledge of the dielectric.

I want to model this capacitor as a subcircuit element.

How do I model metal sheet resistance into the capacitor series resistance?

Also, I want to account for multiple frequencies, so I think the model needs to include multiple parallel branches.

Comment: Justify why ESL doesn't need to be modelled?

Comment: for a coarse estimate you could assume multiple lumps of RCL. For anything more solid and estimating resonances, you would need a Finite Element Solver

Comment: @andy 
Within die, I think ESL does not play much role, as the spacing b/w vdd and vss metal tracks are much smaller. and the via to via gap is around 5um to 10um, so overall loop area is much lower, resulting in very low loop inductance. 
For metal plates and tracks, I dont have the shelf inductance value, dropping L should not have much impact.

Answer (score 0):

This will become more involved than you probably think:

First of all, you need to define the geometry, because, clearly, the effective resistance depends on where how much current flows.

But modeling the plates as anything but a perfect conductor means that you can't assume the charge density to be the same all over plates – exactly *because* a charge has lost energy from the feed to the point it sits "on the inner surface". If you don't model that energy loss, then there's no metal resistance.

So, now you have an interesting  differential equation, because the field that builds up defines the current flows, which give the paths along which you need to integrate the resistivity to get to an effective resistance. But: the field isn't homogenous, and you'll need to calculate the position of the charges!

That also means that your whole ESR, just like in any other real-world capacitor, depends on the frequency you observe it. Maxwell is here to safe (or ruin, depending on what you're hoping for) your day.

And things get ugly: you can't solve this thing without defining boundary conditions. That *also* means you can't solve this sensibly if you're assuming the E-field is perfectly normal to the plates, and doesn't exist outside of the gap: Your plate capacitor needs to also consider the edge effects.

You, honestly, can't solve that analytically in the general case. You might construct special capacitor geometries where you can (and it still won't be pretty) make sufficient simplifications ($\varepsilon_r$ between the plates much larger than outside, capacitor rotationally symmetric with feed all along the circular edge, things like that), but realistically, this is a case for finite element methods of EM simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration on how difficult it is to achieve a PERFECT modelling. My aim here is to draw a approximate model, good for 90% accuracy. Mainly I am think how to translate the sheet resistance into ESR of the cap.

Comment: for 90% accuracy, your ESR = 0Ω at 1 kHz to 10 MHz. Big deal!